# Problema al retornar Json desde Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

me enfrento al siguiente problema.

Opero un array que obtengo de un procedimiento almacenado, el problema sucede que cuando lo retorno al ajax, este me llega vacío sin embargo sí hago un print del array que voy a operar sí puedo visualizar los resultados.

Este es el código del controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá recibo la respuesta del controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que veo cuando hago el print y el die.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo si hago el echo del json para tratarlo en el ajax, obtengo esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de donde esté el error? Esto ya me está volviendo loco!!

Comment: Que pasa si agregas en el ajax, `dataType: 'json', para que pueda parsear la info que recibe.

Comment: Hola, si me faltó agregarlo, la solución en sí fue codificar a utf8 la data que tenía que devolver al ajax.